# getting error adding multiple attributes using .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add multiple html attributes in html tag using `.attr()`but I'm getting the following error in my firebug console:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
[Break On This Error]      
aria-selected: true,   
#PrizeBondSearch (line 149, col 22)
```

Here is the code that I tried:

```
$('ul.k-group').find('a[href="#' + url + '"]').addClass('k-state-selected k-state-focused').parent().attr({
    aria - selected: true,
    id: 'panelbar_pb_active'
});
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error or how to solve it.
If there is any other better way, I will be glad to know of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the way you set the "aria-selected" - you should use quotes as it contains "-":

```
{
    "aria-selected": true,
    id: 'panelbar_pb_active'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct synthax is:

```
$('ul.k-group').find('a[href="#' + url + '"]').addClass('k-state-selected k-state-focused').parent().attr({
          "aria-selected": true,
          id: 'panelbar_pb_active'

      });
```

See aria-selected wrapped in double-quotes (or could be single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote `aria-selected` because it has `-` in it.